# ALTER command denied

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a trigger for my database. Before I do that, I need to remove the error (foreign key constraint fails). To remove it, I ran the code SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `employees` to see if all the collation values are the same. I found that two foreign keys had different values, like this:

```
Field            Type            Collation
officeCode       varchar(10)     latin1_swedish_ci
reportsTo        int(11)         NULL
```

So I tried to change the collation of `reportsTo` by running this code:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER TABLE `employees`.`reportsTo` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

And then I got this error message:

> ALTER command denied to user 'name'@'localhost' for table 'reportsTo'

My question:

How do I get rid of this error message? I can't change the collation of `officeCode` since it is assigned to each employee of the `employees` table.

Comment: You don't have permission to alter.

Comment: @Robert How do I get the permission?

Comment: ask your administrator

Comment: also you should consider using utf8mb4

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with collation. It's a privilege problem - you don't have the required permission to ALTER.

Comment: `reportsTo` is an integer. Numeric values, including integers, don't use collations. Character sets and collations are for text columns.

Comment: @nbk It's what my instructor assigned as a default collation so I'm not really sure if it's okay to just change it

Comment: `.. @'localhost'` means you're doing it locally.. is this your own PC or what?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular II was actually worried about that too. I need to make it work so that I can create a trigger but it keeps showing a 'foreign key constraint fails error message' before I even run any code related to creating a trigger.

Comment: @FanoFN It's phpMyAdmin that my college gives access to me.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for your reply. I requested a permission to my instructor